# SQL - Creating View with multiple CTEs

Tags: sql, sql-view, sql-cte

I have a View to create, which has 2 CTES.
This is what I have done below.
The first part is fine, but after "AND"
things do not work. Your input is appreciated

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.VW.SPAg
AS With today as 
(SELECT * FROM dbo.Work_Days
 WHERE [Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)

AND WITH rd as
(SELECT [DATE] AS REP_DATE
 FROM dbo.Link_Days
 WHERE DAY ([DATE]) = 1
)
SELECT wm *,
gr.DATE_ORDINAL AS Goods_Rcvd_Ordinal
gt.DATE_ORDINAL AS Goods_Trnpt_Ordinal
today.DATE

FROM dbo.SPAg sg
INNER JOIN rd
  ON YEAR(sg.Client_Query)= YEAR(rd.REP_DATE)
LEFT JOIN dbo.Work_DAYS gr
ON sg.Goods_Rcvd = gr.[DATE]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Work_DAYS gt
ON sg.Goods_Trnpt = gt.[DATE]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To specify multiple steps [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) use `,`

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.VW.SPAg   /* [dbo].[VW_SPAg] Probably you want this name*/
AS 
WITH today as 
(SELECT * FROM dbo.Work_Days
 WHERE [Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
), rd as
(SELECT [DATE] AS REP_DATE
 FROM dbo.Link_Days
 WHERE DAY ([DATE]) = 1
)
SELECT wm *,
gr.DATE_ORDINAL AS Goods_Rcvd_Ordinal
gt.DATE_ORDINAL AS Goods_Trnpt_Ordinal
today.DATE
FROM dbo.SPAg sg
INNER JOIN rd
  ON YEAR(sg.Client_Query)= YEAR(rd.REP_DATE)
LEFT JOIN dbo.Work_DAYS gr
  ON sg.Goods_Rcvd = gr.[DATE]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Work_DAYS gt
  ON sg.Goods_Trnpt = gt.[DATE];
```

Also I don't like view name `dbo.VW.SPAg`, do you have database called `[dbo]`? Or it should be `[dbo].[VW_SPAg]`?

Comment: Thanks lad2025. It worked. Amazing how an extra pair of eyes can help.

Comment: @Speedio Happy to hear it works.